# loop - for(i=0; i<n; i++) equivalent

Tags: loops, for-loop

What is the exact execution flow for `for(i=0; i<n; i++)`?

Is it:

```
i=0;
while (true) {
  if (i<n) {
    i++;
    //loop body
  }
  else {
    break;
  }
}
```

And is `for (i=0; i<n; i++)` equivalent to `for (i=0; i++<n;)`, why or why not?
This is a non-language-specific question. But to make it clear, let's say in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is equivalent except for one detail, the counter is incremented after the loop body. With your version, printing `i` in every iteration would output 1 as the first number, but a classic `for` loop will start at 0. Besides, the `if` is redundant since you can move its condition into the `while` loop and avoid the `break` altogether:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < n) {
    //body
    i++;
}
```

`for (i=0; i++<n;)` is not correct either as it will increase `i` within the bounds check, meaning you have the same problem as before: `i` will be 1 in the first body iteration.